# Верна ли расстановка запятых?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Название турнира – «Могущество атлантов» – говорило само за себя, так же, как и состав участников....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Название турнира – «Могущество атлантов» – говорило само за себя, так же как и состав участников...

С тире согласна, можно выделить как пояснение, а вот ***так же как*** - составной союз, условий для его разделения запятой нет, на "так же" фразовое ударение не падает, если только как авторское.

Answer (score 0):

Исхожу из того, что в цитате мы видим полное предложение, просто оно завершено многоточием.

**Название турнира – «Могущество атлантов» – говорило само за себя, также как и состав участников....**

Думаю, здесь *также* нужно писать слитно.

> Также как, в зн. союза. Он владеет французским, также как и немецким. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5))

И название турнира, и состав участников говорили сами за себя.